Show that $\int_0^1\frac{\cos(t)}{t-z}dt+\int_2^3\frac{\sin(t)}{t-z}dt$ admits a Laurent series expansion on $1<|z|<2$ and determine this expansion
Show that the function
$$
F(z) := \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(t)}{t-z} \, dt + \int_2^3 \frac{\sin(t)}{t-z} \, dt
$$
admits a Laurent series expansion in the annulus $1 < |z| < 2$, and determine this expansion.
my attempt:
The function $F(z)$ is holomorphic in the annulus $1 < |z| < 2$ because,

The integrand $\frac{\cos(t)}{t-z}$ is holomorphic with respect to $z$ for $z \neq t$. Since $t \in [0,1]$ and $z$ satisfies $ |z| > 1 $, there are no singularities of this term in the region $1 < |z| < 2$.
Similarly, the integrand $\frac{\sin(t)}{t-z}$ is holomorphic for $z \neq t$. Since $t \in [2,3]$ and $z$ satisfies $ |z| < 2 $, this term also has no singularities in the annulus.

Thus, $F(z)$ is holomorphic in $1 < |z| < 2$.
For the term
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(t)}{t-z} dt,
$$
since $ |z| > 1 $ and $ t \in [0,1] $, we have $ \left| \frac{t}{z} \right| < 1 $. This allows the geometric series expansion:
$$
\frac{1}{t-z} = -\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{t}{z} \right)^n,
$$
valid for $ |t/z| < 1 $. Substituting this into the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(t)}{t-z} dt = -\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} \int_0^1 t^n \cos(t) \, dt.
$$
and for the other term I consider similarly and get
$$
F(z) = -\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} \int_0^1 t^n \cos(t) \, dt + \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \int_2^3 \frac{\sin(t)}{t^{n+1}} dt.
$$
is this well?

Looks good to me. Note that computation is basically the Laurent expansion of ${1 \over t-z}$ for the two ranges of $t$:
$a_n = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_{|z|={3 \over 2}} {F(z) \over z^{n+1}(t-z)} dz = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_0^1 \cos t\int_{|z|={3 \over 2}} {1 \over z^{n+1}(t-z)} dz dt + {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_2^3 \sin t\int_{|z|={3 \over 2}} {1 \over z^{n+1}(t-z)} dz dt$.
